# My vertical navigation is only as high as my window, don't know why

Tags: css, html, overflow

When the content of the site is bigger then the window (no matter how high you make the window, this rule applies). This is very unwanted behavior because it looks like #@!*...

I'm quite new to webdesign so I probably really made some big mistakes in my css.. Here is the css file, hope someone can point it out.. (probably using height: 100% was bad, but don't know what else to do =/.

And I know for content and stuff absolute is REALLY bad.

This is what the 'bug' looks like, at the bottom when the content is larger then the window:
http://i49.tinypic.com/1zqa9th.png

Here is a html skeleton:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <?php 
    $title_tags = "TITLE HERE";
    $meta_description = "";
    include('generalhead.php'); ?>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar">
                        <div class = "wrap1">
        <img src="media/images/blub.png" class="blub"><br>

        <div class="cloud">
        <img src="media/images/dots.gif">
        <img class="cloud_text" src="media/images/cloud.png">
        <img src="media/images/dots.gif">
        </div>

        <div class="menu">
            <ul id="nav" class="navig">
                <h3 class="big_link"><a href="index.php">home</a></h3>      
                <h3 class="big_link"><a href="contact.php">contact</a></h3>                 
                <h3>Algemene dakwerken</h3>
                <li><a href="epdm.php">Epdm</a></li>
                <li><a href="pannen.php">pannen</a></li>
                <li><a href="zink.php">zink</a></li>
                <li><a href="koper.php">koper</a></li>
                <li><a href="dakconstructie.php">dakconstructie</a></li>
                <li><a href="velux.php">velux steken</a></li>
                <li><a href="oversteking.php">uitbekleden oversteking</a></li>
                <h3>binnenhuisinrichting</h3>
                <li><a href="ramen_deuren.php">ramen en deuren</a></li>
                <li><a href="gyproc.php">gyproc</a></li>
                <li><a href="muren_plafonds.php">muren en plafonds</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="content-top">
                <div class="content-head">
                blub
                </div>

                <div class="content-body">
                    CONTENT TEXT COMES HERE, BELLOW THIS ARE THE CONTENT PICTURES
                </div>

                <div class="content-pictures">
                    <!-- Slider-->
                    <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">

                        <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                            <?php 
                                $directory_name = "index";
                                include ("generate_photo_content.php");
                            ?>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <?php include ('bottomscripts.php'); ?>
  </body>
</html>​
```

CSS HERE

```css
    body{
    /* FALLBACK KLEUR ALS GRADIENT NIET WERKT*/
    background-color: #1b1000;

    height: 100%;
    font-size: 100%
}

/*ROND ALLES EN ZORGT VOOR GRADIENT OP BACKGROUND*/
.wrapper{
    display:block;

    /*set the div in the top-left corner of the screen*/
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;

    /*set the width and height to 100% of the screen*/
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;

    /* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
    background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(left center, circle farthest-side, #4D2D0F 0%, #1B1000 50%, #1B1000 100%);

    /* Mozilla Firefox */ 
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(left center, circle farthest-side, #4D2D0F 0%, #1B1000 50%, #1B1000 100%);

    /* Opera */ 
    background-image: -o-radial-gradient(left center, circle farthest-side, #4D2D0F 0%, #1B1000 50%, #1B1000 100%);

    /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, left center, 0, left center, 973, color-stop(0, #4D2D0F), color-stop(0.5, #1B1000), color-stop(1, #1B1000));

    /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(left center, circle farthest-side, #4D2D0F 0%, #1B1000 50%, #1B1000 100%);

    /* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-side at left center, #4D2D0F 0%, #1B1000 50%, #1B1000 100%);
}

.sidebar {
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: #ffcc00;
    /*background-image: url(../images/bar-8.png);*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(../images/bar.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 0px 6px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 0px 6px #000000;
    box-shadow: 5px 0px 6px #000000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.wrap1{
    position: relative;
    top:15px;
    }

.logo{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 4px;
}

.blub{
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.cloud{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%
}
.cloud_text{
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.menu{
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}


.menu {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    font-size: 0.8125em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navig{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.navig > li > a{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c68f00;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    text-indent: 16px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Areal, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #603913;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
}
.navig > h3{
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #c68f00;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.25em;
    line-height: 2.75em;
    text-indent: 10px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Areal, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #603913;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.navig > li > a:hover,
.navig > li > a:active{
     background-color: #fdda01;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(252, 219, 0)),to(rgb(255,204,0)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(252, 219, 0), rgb(255,204,0));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(252, 219, 0), rgb(255,204,0));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(252, 219, 0), rgb(255,204,0));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(252, 219, 0), rgb(255,204,0));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgb(252, 219, 0), rgb(255,204,0));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#45c7eb', EndColorStr='#2698db');
    border-bottom: 1px solid #886304;
}

.big_link > a {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #c68f00;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.25em;
    line-height: 2.75em;
    text-indent: 10px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    color: #603913;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.big_link> a:active,
.big_link > a:hover{
    background-color: #fdda01;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(252, 219, 0)),to(rgb(255,204,0)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(252, 219, 0), rgb(255,204,0));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(252, 219, 0), rgb(255,204,0));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(252, 219, 0), rgb(255,204,0));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(252, 219, 0), rgb(255,204,0));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgb(252, 219, 0), rgb(255,204,0));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#45c7eb', EndColorStr='#2698db');
    border-bottom: 2px solid #886304;
}

.selected{
    background-color: #fdda01;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(252, 219, 0)),to(rgb(255,204,0)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(252, 219, 0), rgb(255,204,0));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(252, 219, 0), rgb(255,204,0));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(252, 219, 0), rgb(255,204,0));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(252, 219, 0), rgb(255,204,0));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgb(252, 219, 0), rgb(255,204,0));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#45c7eb', EndColorStr='#2698db');
    border-bottom: 1px solid #886304;

}
```

Comment: And what's your HTML? And could you show us a live demo, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar?

Comment: Is the problem solved when you remove `height:100%;` ? And why are you using `absolute` ?

Comment: I added the html so you get the div hierarchy, sorry for not including it in the first place

Comment: I also just added a picture of what the bug looks like..

Comment: AND updated the include navigation to the actual navigation from the file

Comment: please help, really need this one answered

Comment: You should NOT post so much code. Only the relevant part. What have you tried so far? Where do you think lies the problem? Etc. We can't start extracting every bit of unuseful information ... Even better: give us a test case (live site or jsfiddle). Keep this in mind for your nexdt topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Short answer:**

Here's your current HTML markup and CSS definitions with the ending result as requested:

See this working [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/KP8c5/2/)!

[image]

---

### **Long Answer**

Your current code as presented on the question contains several markup issues:

1. **Child elements** of an unordered list (`UL`):

   See the [W3C - Lists in HTML documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html)

   `<ul/>` element can only have `<li/>` as a child. Currently you're placing `<h3/>` mixed with `<li/>` elements.
2. **Closing tags** for the `<div/>` element:

   - You're using **12** opening tags.
   - You're using **13** closing tags.
   - Loose one closing `div` declaration after your `ul` to have the markup working as expected.

---

### **Regarding your sidebar height issue**

I've tried to work with the code you've provided, but the structure is to messy to achieve your goal with a plain CSS solution.

So I went the other way around, prepared the desired structure to have your contents applied to it. The markup on this [**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/KP8c5/) solves your issue.

**HTML MARKUP** <sup>the basic layout</sup>

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li>Sidebar stuff.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>     
    <div class="content">
        CONTENT TEXT COMES HERE, BELLOW THIS ARE THE CONTENT PICTURES
        </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS** <sup>the basics to prepare the layout</sup>

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.clear { clear: both; }
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffcc00;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.content {
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

*All you have to do is to apply this markup and fill it with your contents.*

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and efforts!